# Regex to allow integers between 0-9 with maximum of two decimal places

Tags: regex

I have this regex `^[0-9]\.[0-9]{1, 2}$`. Valid values should be between 0-9 and only 1 or 2 decimal places allowed i.e

1.11 - CORRECT
1.1 - CORRECT

1.111 - WRONG
22.11 - WRONG

However, I enter a value like 112 and it allows it! Any corrections?

Comment: There should be no space in `{1, 2}`. Besides, depending on how you initialize the regex, you may need to double the backslash or put it into a character class. `^[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}$` or `^[0-9][.][0-9]{1,2}$` should work.

Comment: There is some key information missing, apart from the space in `1, 2` the regex seems correct - but that should usually result in an error of any kind.

Comment: I think your regex work fine: https://regex101.com/r/mjPtjt/2

Comment: @cSteusloff – Your interpretation of that regex corrected Brian's erroneous whitespace (see Wiktor's comment above) and does not match the example text (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Your original regex:

```
^[0-9]\.[0-9]{1, 2}$
```

[Explained](https://regex101.com/r/qwAmeV/1):

- `^`: must start a line
- `[0-9]`: a digit
- `\.`: a literal dot
- `[0-9]`: a number
- `{1, 2}`: literally match that string (this is due to your space)
- `$`: must end a line

Your test content doesn't end lines with numbers:

```
1.11 - CORRECT 1.1 - CORRECT
1.111 - WRONG 22.11 - WRONG
```

To match your test content, you need to remove that space and the end-line marker:

```
^[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\s
```

I've added a required whitespace character to ensure you don't have another dot and number like `1.11.1`.  This [refined version explained](https://regex101.com/r/qwAmeV/2):

- ... (see above)
- `[0-9]{1,2}`: one or two digits
- `\s`: a whitespace character (usually space or tab, usually not line feed or carriage return)